# Missing Scaling Factor of the Electric Field of Hermite-Gaussian Modes

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electric-fields, photonics

I am currently looking at A. Yariv's book "Introduction to Optical Electronics" 2nd edition. In Chapter 3 "Propagation of Optical Beams in Homogenous and Guiding Media", Yariv gives two formulas for the analytical solution of the electric field.

The first is the fundamental Gaussian beam. $$E(x,y,z)=E_0\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}exp\left(-i[kz-\eta(z)]-r^2\left(\frac{1}{\omega^2(z)}+\frac{ik}{2R(z)}\right)\right)$$

The second describes the Hermite-Gaussian modes.
$$E_{l,m}(x,y,z) = E_0\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}H_l\left(\sqrt{2}\frac{x}{\omega(z)}\right)H_m\left(\sqrt{2}\frac{y}{\omega(z)}\right)\times$$
$$\times exp\left[-\frac{x^2+y^2}{\omega^2(z)}-\frac{ik(x^2+y^2)}{2R(z)}-ikz+i(l+m+1)\eta(z)\right]$$

Here, $E_0$ is the complex field amplitude, $\omega(z)$ is the beam radius at location $z$ ($\omega_0$ is the beam waist), $R(z)$ is the radius of curvature of the wavefront, and $\eta(z)$ is the impedance.

I decided to make a small visualization in Python using the two formulas provided. I set the field amplitude $E_0=1$ and plotted the field profile in $(x,y,z=0)$.

The result which I got for the fundamental Gaussian beam was as expected. Where the field intensity is 1 at the center of the beam and decays as the radius increases. Here I propagated the beam in the $z$ direction.

[image]

I then plotted the cross-section of several Hermite-Gaussian beams at $z=0$ using the second formula and noticed that there isn't any scaling factor in the formula and the field amplitude keeps increasing as you increase the mode. In the below plot you can see that the field intensity is of the order of $10^{10}$.

[image]

My question is: Is it normal that the intensity of the higher order modes is of the order of  $10^{10}$? Shouldn't the intensity amplitude be equal to 1, as in the case of the fundamental Gaussian beam? If yes - what scaling factor can I include in the second formula to make it correct?